# Different headings on the chapterpages in different parts (documentclass{book})

Tags: sectioning, fancyhdr

I would like to have different headers (defined in normal1 and normal2) for the chapter pages (first page in the chapters) in the different parts of the book. I get the same chapter page in every parts with my code.

I get
First chapter page: [image]

Second chapter page:[image]

I want the second chapter page to look like: [image]

I have tried to redefine \patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{normal}{}{}  inside the document but it doesn't work.

My code in the preamble:

```
\fancypagestyle{normal}{%
    \renewcommand\headrulewidth{1pt}
    \fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textit{Just in first chapter:}  \lastleftxmark~\firstrightxmark}
    %\fancyhead[RO]{\lastleftxmark~\firstrightxmark}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}}

\fancypagestyle{normal2}{%
    \renewcommand\headrulewidth{1pt}
    \fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\lastleftxmark~\firstrightxmark}
    %\fancyhead[RO]{\lastleftxmark~\firstrightxmark}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{normal}{}{}
```

My code in the document before part 2:

```
\patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{normal2}{}{}
```

Comment: But the page style doesn't involve the chapter page (the first page in a chapter), or does it? When I'm not using \patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{normal2}{}{} I don't get any headings on the first page in a chapter. Or can I fix that in another way?

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

One of the things `\chapter` does is issue the command `\thispagestyle{plain}`, which changes the page style of that one page to plain.  Your `patchcmd` is a complicated attempt to change that to `\thispagestyle{normal2}`.  I'm not sure why it doesn't work, but there are easier approaches than pulling out `\patchcmd`.

The simplest would be to follow up your `\chapter` commands with `\thispagestyle{normal2}`.

Another approach would be to redefine the plain page style by calling

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \renewcommand\headrulewidth{1pt}
    \fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\lastleftxmark~\firstrightxmark}
    %\fancyhead[RO]{\lastleftxmark~\firstrightxmark}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
}
```

after the "First chapter in part 1" page (see page 10 in the fancyhdr texdoc).